# Get name of activity inside a library used in the project

Tags: android, android-activity, package, android-library

I would like to get the name of an activity in a android library I imported. I have to preicse that I a m not looking to get the name of current package. I already tried with the following code :

```
        PackageManager pManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packs = pManager.getInstalledPackages(0);

        //get all packages names
        for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            Log.v("getIntent", "Installed package : " + packs.get(i).toString());
        }
```

But I didn't get the name of the library with other packages... How can I get the name the activity in the library then ?